# Concurrency in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using the core data for fetching/ saving the data. In my application, I use 90 % of core data and 10 % with web services API. Currently, I'm working on optimization. Earlier I tried with NSOperationQueue and GCD operations. I found - performBlock: and - performBlockAndWait: to resolve the thread operations and asynchronous(background) process.  This was more suitable for my code. I initiated managedobjectContext with concurrencytype as NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType.

**Is it good to have NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType alone throughout the application ? **

```
NSManagedObjectContext *private = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's OK to use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` everywhere. It might not be convenient but that's up to you.

The advantage of `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` is that if your code is running on the main queue, you don't need `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait`. Those methods would just run the block on the main queue, but when you're already on the main queue, that doesn't make a difference. This can make UI-related code simpler. Whether to use it is your call, depending on what you find convenient to do in your code.

Comment: But the app gets crashed when I use NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType alone.

Comment: Then you should post a question where you describe the crash and include code that causes it. Using private queue concurrency is fine, but any code can be a problem if it’s not written right.